# How to programatically assign variables in simple MediaWiki templates?

Tags: templates, variables, math, mediawiki

I'm making a MediaWiki template that uses variables (e.g., "height=72", "weight=180", sex="1"), and I need to do some long-winded mathematics using those by way of ParserFunctions, at numerous places throughout the template.  With my limited understanding of the syntax, I've had to paste these huge formulae over and over again, cluttering up the template.  The ideal solution, I think, would be to find a way to programatically assign new variables (or at least change the value of existing ones) to help condense things.  Is there a way to do that using the standard MediaWiki installation?

*[Edit: The question in this second paragraph, I believe I've solved, though the passing of many variables ends up being nearly as long as the formula being replaced!]*  Alternatively, if I can't change a variable once set, then I'll have to rely on these long formulae being called numerous times throughout the template -- in which case, I would like to find a way of offloading each formula to its own template, such that I could type "{{CalculateWeight}}" instead of pasting the complicated weight calculation each time.  However, in my attempts at implementing this method, I've discovered that the variables from my template do not carry over to the secondary template containing the math expression.

I don't know how to describe the gyrations I've attempted to solve this.  I'm entirely new to MediaWiki programming, and with my lack of understanding have simply brute-forced my way to some success.  The following solution sounds like the latter half of my problem, but the post was made eight years ago, and I've read that the Variables extension is now on it's way out.  [MediaWiki templates inherit parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164710/mediawiki-templates-inherit-parameters)

*[Edit 2:  As requested, my replies to a comment being added to the original post.]*  I have a series of wiki pages, each setting a number of variables for use in the template.  In ParserFunctions format, the most repeated calculation (as I don't yet have a way to set new variables) is typically a line or two in length.  The math indeed has to be done, as the variables are designed to provide a highly customized mathematical result for each page using the template.  In the hours since posting, however, I think I've managed to place the long formula into its own template (though having to pass half a dozen variables is almost as long as using the formula alone).

*[Edit 2 continued.]*  To clarify what I'm asking for in the post's first paragraph: Basically I'd like some way to say "Take the result of this calculation and temporarily hold it as Variable X, so I can use that amount in other calculations on this particular page."

Comment: First thought: is any of that math _really necessary_? What is it for? (E.g. is this something you can just set a CSS variable for, and then just write appropriate CSS using query selectors, `var()`, and `calc()`). Basically: what are you trying to _achieve_ that makes you think you need variables and math inside the template (because you may be right, but then again: you may not be)

Comment: I have a series of wiki pages, each setting a number of variables for use in the template.  In ParserFunctions format, the most repeated calculation (as I don't yet have a way to set new variables) is typically a line or two in length.  The math indeed has to be done, as the variables are designed to provide a highly customized mathematical result for each page using the template.  In the hours since posting, however, I *think* I've managed to place the long formula into its own template (though having to pass half a dozen variables is almost as long as using the formula alone).

Comment: To clarify what I'm asking for in the post's first paragraph:  Basically I'd like some way to say "Take the result of this calculation and temporarily hold it as Variable X, so I can use that amount in other calculations on this particular page."

Comment: (Please [edit] your post to include that information. [details should not be in comments](/help/how-to-ask), so if someone asks for more details, that's a request to update the post =)

Comment: Install Scribunto and write a module.

Comment: "Install Scribunto and write a module," Mr. Mashin?  You might as well have said, "Learn magic and cast a spell."

Comment: @user182238 Not really, Wikitext, when stretched beyond its limits, which is what the topic starter obviously does, is more esoteric than any programming code. If someone can write an overcomplicated wiki template, he could as well write a little Lua program.

Comment: You could begin with dividing your task into two parts: the first, doing the calculations; the second -- presenting the calculated values. The second part should be a template or several templates, as simple as possible; the first, a module, doing the calculations and then invoking the presentation template(s) with `frame:expandTemplate()` and passing the calculated values to them.

Comment: Also, you should not use the Variables extension (or any other extension) to store the results of some intermediate calculations for later reuse. After the switch to Parsoid, wikitext is no longer guaranteed to be parsed in a certain order. Consider it a pure function. Your variable may be invoked before it is set. Either repeat your calculations, hoping that they will be cached by the parser cache, or, as I have said, use Lua.